# Set relative output directory in R

Tags: r

I have an R script which reads data from multiple xlsx files, converts them into a dataframe and then creates folders in a directory at my computer based on the row values of the dataframe. I've set the main directory in the beginning of my code like that:

`choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")`

And the output directory where the folders are created, as:

`pth <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/test/"`

I want to run the script at multiple computers, which means that the output directory named *pth* will not always be the same. Is there a way to set a relative output path, so that every time I run the script to specify where I want my results to be located? I tried

`pth <- choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Choose the output path")`

Although a dialogue window pops up and I choose the desired directory, I can't see any of the folders there.

This is my code so far:

```
#choose working directory
choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")

library(xlsx)
library(tcltk)

#get file names
f = list.files("./")

#read files
dat <- lapply(tk_choose.files(caption="Choose your files"), function(i) {
  x <- read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
                 endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE, Filters = Filters[c("xlsx")])
  #return columns with names and colors
  x <- x[, c(2, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19), drop = FALSE]
  #return the data
  x
})

library(plyr)
df1 <- ldply(dat, data.frame) ## convert list into a dataframe

#remove NA's
complete.cases(df1)
x <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
str(x)

#show specific rows
df1$X2 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","-",df1$X2)
df <-df1[grepl("^[0-9]|^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*", df1$X2), ]
#print(df)

##pth <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/test/"
pth = choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Choose the output path")

# Iteratate within each row of df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (!file.exists(pth))
    # Create 1st path
    dir.create(paste0(pth , df$X2[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  # Create 2nd and 3rd paths
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X5[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X7[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X2[i], "/",df$X9[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X11[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X13[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X15[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X17[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth,  df$X2[i], "/",df$X19[i]), na.omit(df$X2[i]))
}
```

Comment: You could use the home directory (stored as environment variable HOME, accessible by R through ```Sys.getenv("HOME")```) and set the path relative to that home path by ```pth <- "~/Desktop/test/"```

Comment: Denise thank you, but the `Sys.getenv("HOME")` returns _"C:/Users/Dev/Documents"_  and I have no output shown. Also, in other computers the output might need to be shown in a different directory, not necessarily in `~/Desktop/test/`. Is there a more generic statement i could use so that every time someone runs it, they can choose where to output the data?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are developing but you could write your script as a function and supply the path to the local directory as a function input and call the function on each machine by ```MyFunction("path/to/local/directory/")```. If that's not appropriate, you could set a different environment variable ```LOCAL_DIRECTORY``` (or however you want to call it) and access it in the same way than the home directory inside of the script.. disadvantage is that you have to set this environment variable on every machine before being able to run the R code

Answer (score 5):

You can do that using relative path specifiers. For example:

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents/Rdevel/coverage"
setwd("../stackoverflow/")   # .. means go up one directory level
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents/Rdevel/stackoverflow"
setwd("../..")   # go up two levels
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents"
```

This will work on unix as well.

BTW: `.` denotes the actual directory. So,

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents"
setwd("./Rdevel/")   # . denotes actual directory
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents/Rdevel"
```

is equivalent to

```
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents"
setwd("Rdevel")
getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Uwe/Documents/Rdevel"
```

Comment: Good to know, but whenever I run it in a different computer, I will have to edit the code and change the `setwd()` manually, right? I used this to choose the main directory : `choose.dir(getwd(), "Choose a suitable folder")`. I'd like to do the same for my output path, so that a dialogue window pops up and i choose where to show my results. I used `pth <- choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Choose the output path")`, but every time I run it, I can't see any data in the output path. Whereas if I use a specified path, for example `pth <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/test/`, I can see them. Why is that?

Comment: You should edit your Q and add the additional information there.

Comment: After `pth <- choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Choose the output path")` what does `str(pth)` return?

Comment: `chr "C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\test"`